# Read value of <a href> without double quotes in c# using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to read the href value without double quotes in c# using regex.

Input

```
<a href="http://mysite.net.testpage.com/11/General/123456-BT%20Request-2018-01-08T09_17_22.xml?OpenIn=Browser">123456</a>
```

Output Required

```
http://mysite.net.testpage.com/11/General/123456-BT%20Request-2018-01-08T09_17_22.xml?OpenIn=Browser
```

Comment: [Legendary post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - or: use HtmlAgilityPack or similar

Comment: What regular-expression do you have so far and what happens when you try to use it? ...or are you just asking us to write it for you?

Comment: @MarcGravell It *is* appropriate to use regular-expressions to extract individual attributes from HTML.

Comment: @Dai even *at best* that depends hugely on context

Comment: I am using the regex as - @"(<a href.*?>)"

Comment: @Enigmativity - Can you share the link of earlier asked question.

Comment: @user3106445 - It's at the top of the page and it's the same link that Marc gave.